# Draw multiple line in jqplot using json Data

Tags: jqplot

Iam trying to Draw multiple line in jqplot using json Data 
 I have doubt on jqPlot, i am using json data to plot a chart in jqPlot.I have two sets 
  of json data like this

```
var jsonData1 = {"PriceTicks": [{"Price":5.5,"TickDate":"Jan"}, 
                        {"Price":6.8,"TickDate":"Mar"},
                        {"Price":1.9,"TickDate":"June"},                            
                        {"Price":7.1,"TickDate":"Dec"}]};                               

      var jsonData2 = {"PriceTicks": [{"Price":1.5,"TickDate":"Jan"}, 
                        {"Price":2.8,"TickDate":"Feb"},
                        {"Price":3.9,"TickDate":"Apr"},                         
                        {"Price":9.1,"TickDate":"Dec"}]};
```

suppose i have a javascript arrays i can call like this

```
$.jqplot('chartdiv', [cosPoints, sinPoints, powPoints1, powPoints2, powPoints3],
        {
          title:'Line Style Options',
          seriesDefaults: {
            showMarker:false,                           
        },  

        }
      );
```

where cosPoints,sinePoints etc are the javascript arrays in the similar way i have to 
  call the json data , i Used the following way it is failed ,please help me.

```
$.jqplot('jsonChartDiv', [jsonData1,jsonData2] {
          title:'Fruits',
          series:[{showMarker:false}],
          dataRenderer: $.jqplot.ciParser,            
          axes: {
              xaxis: {
                  renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,                     
              }
          },

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to get the ciParser Renderer Plugin to work with your Data Format Requirement.

In the following jsFiddle you see a working example to convert your JSON objects to the required datastructure which is needed to display a Line Chart.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwgjr/2/)

```
// get array with both series
arSeries = [jsonData1, jsonData2];

// initalizat the output array for jqPlot
arJQ = [];

// for each Data Series 
for (var z = 0; z < arSeries.length; z++)
{
    // array for the prices
    jqPrices = [];
    var prices = arSeries[z].PriceTicks;
    for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
    {
        jqPrices.push([prices[i].TickDate.toString(), prices[i].Price]);
    }
    // Result [["Jan",1.5],["Feb",2.8],["Apr",3.9],["Dec",9.1]]
    // add to series array
    arJQ.push(jqPrices);
}
```

To prevent the line going backward you should spedify either your date more granular or with the same tickes on each data record.